# how to draggable items return when finish after drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can't choose and drag item return when finish after drop

Here my code http://jsfiddle.net/T3VY6/

I want to drag multiple row between two table

**Script**

```
    $("#tbodyMember tr").click(function(e) {
        $("#tbodyNotMember").find('tr').removeClass("selected");               
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
    $("#tbodyNotMember tr").click(function(e) { 
        $("#tbodyMember").find('tr').removeClass("selected");         
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    });
    $(".connectedSortable tr").draggable({
        helper: function(){
            var selected = $('.connectedSortable tr.selected');
            if (selected.length === 0) {
                selected = $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
            var container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'connectedSortable');
            container.append(selected.clone().removeClass("selected"));
            return container;
         }
    }); 
    $("#tbodyMember").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui){             
            $(this).find('tr:last').after($(ui.helper.children()));
            $('#tbodyNotMember tr.selected').remove();
        }
    }); 
    $("#tbodyNotMember").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui){        
            $(this).find('tr:last')
                    .after($(ui.helper.children()));
            $('#tbodyMember tr.selected').remove();       
        }
    });
```

Comment: Maybe you should use `sortable()`? http://jsfiddle.net/7UmY7/

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind draggable event to cloned tr element.

Look at updated Code: http://jsfiddle.net/XN2Vh/

```
 function draggableHelper(){
            var selected = $('.connectedSortable tr.selected');
            if (selected.length === 0) {
                selected = $(this).addClass('selected');
            }
            var container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'connectedSortable');
            container.append(selected.clone().removeClass("selected").draggable({
                    helper: draggableHelper
                }));
            return container;
         }
    $(".connectedSortable tr").draggable({
        helper: draggableHelper
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep your draggable event handlers on your copies. You can do this by giving true to the clone method.

I would rather actually move the selected (and their handlers) items rather than clonning them.
Here is how :

```
$("#tbodyMember").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui){             
            $(this).append($('tr.selected'));
            $('#tbodyNotMember tr.selected').remove();
        }
    }); 
    $("#tbodyNotMember").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui){        
            $(this).append($('tr.selected'));
            $('#tbodyMember tr.selected').remove();       
        }
    });
```

see : 
 * [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
 * [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)